# S3 move current objects to Glacier Deep Archive storage class

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, storage, amazon-glacier

I have 1.5TB of data in bucket with *Standard* storage class. I want to move all objects to *Glacier Deep Archive* storage class.

S3 makes a copy (version) of an object in *Standard* storage class If I move it to *Glacier Deep Archive* via GUI (select objects->actions->edit storage class).

Do I get charged for both objects (versions?) or just for the *Glacier* one? Both versions are the same size.

I could use Lifecycle rules but not all files were created >180days ago.

Comment: Do you have Versioning activated on the bucket? If not, you are only charged for the current storage class of the object.

Comment: @Marcin I set lifecycle rules to migrate objects into Deep Archive storage class. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are getting charged for the whole volume including the versions.

But instead of manual update of the storage class, maybe a lifecycle policy is better option, where the objects you can archive the the objects and specify to delete the versionins after some time. No need to wait 180 days

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-lifecycle-management-update/

Answer (score 0):

> I could use Lifecycle rules but not all files were created >180days ago.

You can transition them at any time. They **don't have to be 180 days old**. The `180 days` limit is for getting them back from Deep Archive. If you try to restore your files before they have been in DA for 180, you will be charged penalties for that.

Answer (score 0):

You'll get charged for both objects (versions). From S3 FAQs:

> Normal Amazon S3 rates apply for every version of an object stored or requested